# Cervical spondylosis with disc prolapse at C5-C6 level

Tags: treatment, injury, hernia, spondylosis

My mother is suffering from cervical spondylosis with disc prolapse after an accident. She got whiplash injury.  She was feeling acute pain at that time but pain ha[image]s now reduced. She has been advised by doctor for a traction treatment. What should be the duration of traction treatment and in how many sessions?.. Some docs and physiotherapists are saying it should be continuous for 24 hours but it is not practically possible and a bit controversial as some docs recommended not to use any traction. She also started suffering from vertigo when she changes her position from lying down to sitting. What is the way to get out of it. Please help. I have added image of MRI scan, hope it will be helpful for experts to give a better advice

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). The personal medical advice questions are strictly off-topic here, as the internet cannot replace a face-to-face consultation with your (or in this case your mother's) doctor. With a matter as serious as cervical spine seeing as many specialists as necessary to make an educated decision is the best course of action. I hope all goes well with your mother.